# Is it possible to make a custom "leaving page" confirmation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to be able to pause execution, show a dialog, then when a certain button is pressed, then continue execution.

So if a user is on my form, then clicks a link to a different route, I want my dialog to show up, then if they hit the confirm button on that dialog, the route continues.

So I know there is a $routeChangeStart and it has the next route as the first parameter, but that simply contains the name of the even and some scopes. You can use the preventDefault to stop the route, but I was wondering if there is a way to CONTINUE the route at a later time?

So preferably in routeChangeStart I would do event.preventDefault(), then store next, then after hte user hits confirm, I would take "next" and redo the route.

How do I redo the route?
I know I could do a str_replace on the originalPath using the params object and then $location, but I was wondering if there was a more direct way of re-applying a route change?

Comment: @RobG that's for page reload, in Angular, routes are changed without changing the url (only hash change).

Comment: If no one answer your question, then the best option is to look at the source of the router, if it don't allow this then create your own router using Angular one as base.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I like 90% solved my problem while writing the question, but then the solution looked messy. Still the solution isn't too bad and can be packaged as you said.

Comment: Oh man I'm a fool. $routeChangeStart is discouraged by most and it uses a complicated versino of next and current, but $locationChangeStart simply uses the url for next and current, making the one complication straight forward.
I'll post an answer and complete this. Thanks for everyones help.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you can't avoid the string-parsing.

If you want to handle the confirmation asynchronously, you need to indeed prevent the event by default, ask for the user's confirmation and if granted, set a flag and use `$location.url(...)` to navigate to the requested page.

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($location, $scope, UserConfirm) {
    $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (evt, next, prev) {
        if (!$scope.exitConfirmed) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            var url = extractUrl(prev, next);
            UserConfirm.confirm('Are you sure you want to leave ?').then(
                function (confirmed) {
                    if (confirmed) {
                        $scope.exitConfirmed = true;
                        $location.url(url);
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    });
    ...
});
```

The `extractUrl()` function could look like this:

```
function extractUrl(prevAbsUrl, nextAbsUrl) {
    var idx = prevAbsUrl.length - $location.url().length;
    var withNumSign = nextAbsUrl.substring(idx);
    var pureUrl = withNumSign.substring(withNumSign.indexOf('/'));
    return pureUrl;
}
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/TfQ8v/)**.

Comment: I think you overcomplicated my question =P Next solution though, but it turned out I didn't need string parsing at all.

I truly appreciate you trying to solve my problem. Thank you for your hard work.

Comment: @JasonMcCarrell: It's very similar to how I have solved the same problem on one of my apps. I would be very interested in a simpler solution, so feel free to share if you have one :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use $locationChangeStart,then next and current are simply strings representing the complete urls of your current and future destination, so no parsing is needed.

So my solution was along the lines of:

```
function confirmLeaving(evt, next, current) {
  if(consideringClosing)  //ok we're allowed to leave now
    return;

  evt.preventDefault();  //Don't leave! Show dialog instead.

  $('#dialogCancel').modal('show');
  consideringClosing = true;  //if we try to leave again while dialog is up, thats fine.
}   

$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', confirmLeaving);
```

Then in the modal I have a button "close without saving" that does a $location back to a list of items, but now that I've set consideringClosing to true, confirmLeaving won't stop the user. In the modal is also a cancel button which closes the modal and sets consideringClosing back to false (so the modal will show up again on locationChange).

Comment: OK, so this is the exact same approach I used, with the exception that you don't parse the next location. But how do you navigate to the next location if user confirms ?

Comment: A click event on the "close without saving" button that calls $location.path, because consideringClsoing is now true, the route will occur. the "cancel" button simply closes the modal and sets consideringClosing back to false.

Comment: And what do you pass to $location.path ?

Comment: The "next" parameter that was passed to $locationChangeStart

Comment: Are you sure ? I try `$location.path(next)`, but it doesn't work. Could you prepare a fiddle ? (Only `$location.absUrl(next)` works for me, but I have turned it down for some reason I can't remember :))